# Formatting Google Charts TreeMap Node

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a nice Treemap created for my data, and it's all working and I've managed to get the values appended to the name, but it could be so much better.

The treemaps available in Google Analytics have very differently formatted nodes, including values and child values. Is there a way to format the html block that is rendered for each node like this with the charts we have available to us?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's not much you can do with the standard config options,
except change the text style of the label

however, you can manually change existing or add your own elements to the chart,
once the `'ready'` event fires...

but if you want to move / change the original label,
it will revert back to the original style / location on hover or other activity
have to use a `MutationObserver` to override

see following working snippet for an example of adding additional labels...

the number of children for each location is added, along with a static label --> 'Children'
and the labels are moved to the top left corner, as in the provided picture

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['treemap']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
    ['Global', null, 0, 0],
    ['America', 'Global', 0, 0],
    ['Europe', 'Global', 30, 0],
    ['Asia', 'Global', 10, 0],
    ['Australia', 'Global', 40, 0],
    ['Africa', 'Global', 30, 0],
    [{ v: 'USA', f: 'United States of America' }, 'America', 20, 0],
    ['Mexico', 'America', 24, 12],
    ['Canada', 'America', 16, -23],
    ['Ontario', 'Canada', 12, -9],
    ['Alberta', 'Canada', 24, 13],
    ['UK', 'Europe', 21, -5],
    [{ v: '123', f: 'London' }, 'UK', 21, -5],
    [{ v: '456', f: 'London' }, 'Ontario', 21, -5],
    ['Ohio', 'USA', 12, 3],
    ['Rhode Island', 'USA', 24, 4]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(container);
  var newLabelCoords = {x: 8, y: 16};

  google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'ready', addChildLabels);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', addChildLabels);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(moveOriginalLabels);
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  // find / move original labels
  function moveOriginalLabels() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      var bounds = text.getBBox();
      var rect = text.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];
      if ((rect.getAttribute('fill') !== '#cccccc') && (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle')) {
        text.setAttribute('fill', '#424242');
        text.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');
        text.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) + newLabelCoords.x + (bounds.width / 2));
        text.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('y')) + newLabelCoords.y);
      }
    });
  }

  function addChildLabels() {
    // hold new labels
    var childCount = [];
    var childLabels = [];

    // svg namespace
    var svgNS = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].namespaceURI;

    // find existing / build new labels
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        var rect = text.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];

        // exclude top node
        if (rect.getAttribute('fill') !== '#cccccc') {
          moveOriginalLabels();

          // find node value
          var nodeValue;
          for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            if ((data.getValue(i, 0) === text.textContent) ||
                (data.getFormattedValue(i, 0) === text.textContent)) {
              nodeValue = data.getValue(i, 0);
            }
          }

          // find # of children
          var children = data.getFilteredRows([{
            column: 1,
            value: nodeValue
          }]);

          // add child count
          var textCount = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'text');
          textCount.setAttribute('fill', '#000000');
          textCount.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
          textCount.setAttribute('font-size', '24');
          textCount.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');
          textCount.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) + newLabelCoords.x);
          textCount.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(text.getAttribute('y')) + parseFloat(textCount.getAttribute('font-size')));
          textCount.textContent = children.length;
          childCount.push([text, textCount]);

          // add 'Children' label
          var textLabel = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'text');
          textLabel.setAttribute('fill', '#000000');
          textLabel.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
          textLabel.setAttribute('font-size', text.getAttribute('font-size'));
          textLabel.setAttribute('font-weight', 'bold');
          textLabel.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) + newLabelCoords.x);
          textLabel.setAttribute('y', parseFloat(textCount.getAttribute('y')) + parseFloat(textLabel.getAttribute('font-size')) + 2);
          textLabel.textContent = 'Children';
          childLabels.push([text, textLabel]);
        }
      }
    });

    // append new labels
    childCount.forEach(function (text) {
      text[0].parentNode.appendChild(text[1]);
    });
    childLabels.forEach(function (text) {
      text[0].parentNode.appendChild(text[1]);
    });
  }

  drawTree();
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawTree);
  function drawTree() {
    tree.draw(data, {
      minColor: '#f00',
      midColor: '#ddd',
      maxColor: '#0d0',
      headerHeight: 15,
      fontColor: 'black'
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```